# Proving $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2|x|}{x+1} = 2$ using definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove this limit here

> Prove $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2|x|}{x+1} = 2$, using epsilon-delta or sequence limit definition

Here's the answer I've come up so far

Let $\epsilon > 0 $, by Archimedian Property, then exist $m \in  N$ such that

Consider $\epsilon ' = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon$, it's clear that $\epsilon ' > 0$ then we get $\frac{1}{m} < \epsilon '$

Then, for every $x ≥ m$, we get

$|\frac{2|x|}{x+1} - 2| = |\frac{2|x|-2x-2}{x+1}| = |\frac{2x-2x-2}{x+1} | = |\frac{-2}{x+1} | = \frac{2}{x+1} ≤ \frac {2}{x} \leq \frac{2}{m} < 2\epsilon ' = \epsilon $

limit proven.

Is this correct? also it seems there is another way to prove this? like using epsilon-delta definition.

Any insight would really help, thanks beforehand.

Comment: "Using definition" is quite unclear.  What does that mean?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm sorry, I'll edit it, I think my prof wanted us to prove either by the epsilon-delta or sequence limit definition

Comment: Your manipulation with the inequalities seems like the right strategy. I think you need to be more careful with your $\varepsilon$. Your proof should start as 'Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and choose $m$ so that $\frac{2}{m} < \varepsilon$. Then (inequality stuff)'.

Comment: You start with an arbitrary $\epsilon$ and prove that after some point, the the fraction is within $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the number 2. So I'd say your proof is correct.

Comment: thanks for the insight from you guys :)

Comment: "delta epsilon" is short hand for any of the four types of proof: $\delta-\epsilon$, $\delta-M$, $\epsilon-N$ or $N-M$.  You use $\delta-\epsilon$ to prove $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$.  You use $\delta-M$ to prove $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\pm \infty$.  You use $\epsilon-N$ to prove $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty}f(x)=L$ and you use $N-M$ to prove $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x)=\pm \infty$.  to prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=2$ we need an $\epsilon-N$ proof, that for any $\epsilon$ there is an $N$ so that $n>N$ implies $|\frac{2x}{x+1}-2|<\epsilon$.  That *IS* the type of proof you gave and it was fine.

Comment: " like using epsilon-delta definition."  ..... so you *DID* you the epsilon-delta definition. You just had to use $n > M \implies....$ rather then $|x-c|< \delta$ because you have $x\to \infty$ you cant have $|x - \infty| < \delta$.  What you choose instead is $x > N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the  OP's intent can be understood, it is advised that they carefully "'dot their i's" and "cross their t's" to logically *nail it down* and they can then compare their technique to the one given here.

The OP should understand that

> When taking a limit out to infinity, such as
>
> $\quad \displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = L$
>
> that the  $\delta \gt 0$ 'bit' has a different interpretation (see the last section).

Set $f(x) = \frac{2|x|}{x+1}$. It is easily shown (use inequality algebra) that

$\quad \displaystyle f\bigr(\,[0,+\infty)\,\bigr) \subset [0, 2]$

So we now only have to address a challenge $\varepsilon$ satisfying  $0 \lt \varepsilon \lt 2$.

For $x \gt 0$

$\quad f(x) \ge 2-\varepsilon \text{ iff }$
$\quad \quad  2x \ge 2x + 2 -\varepsilon x  - \varepsilon \text{ iff }$
$\quad \quad  \varepsilon x  \ge 2 - \varepsilon \text{ iff }$
$\quad \quad  x  \ge \frac{2 - \varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$

Setting $d = \frac{2 - \varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$ we can now write as true

$\quad \displaystyle f\bigr(\,[d,+\infty)\,\bigr) \subset [2 - \varepsilon, 2 + \varepsilon]$

and so

$\quad \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2|x|}{x+1} = 2$

---

The reader can review the definition

$\quad$ [Limits at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_at_infinity)

This definition uses strict inequalities and the limit control variable is designated with the letter $c$, but the above is an equivalent formulation.

Heck, you could even use $\delta$ rather that $c$ or $d$, but that would bring a frown to the face of some mathematicians.